# How can I add server plugins on Netbeans?

Tags: tomcat, plugins, netbeans, server

I installed Netbeans on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and I want to add a tomcat server. When I click "Add Server" I get this message:

```
No server plugins are installed in the IDE
The IDE needs a server plugin (e.g. GlassFish plugin) to enable registering and using a server.  Use plugin manager to install server plugins.
```

From a search that I did I found that the problem is NetBeans does not officially support Java EE or web application development so I installed the clicked plugins in the picture below.

[The clicked ones](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kE7QF.png)

But nothing changed - the message is exactly the same. Can someone please help me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The terminology might be confusing you. In your plugins screen shot “available” means “available for installation” rather then “available for use”, so just click that **Install**  button to install the plugins that you had selected. After doing that everything should be fine. Or am I completely misunderstanding your problem?…

Comment: @skomisa I installed the clicked plugins but nothing changed, i will edit my post so it will be more clear. Thank you for you answer!

Answer (score 0):

Finally i uninstalled it and i installed it again, now everything is fine. Probably something gone bad during the first installation.